# Android: passing context in JUnit and use shared preferences

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, junit

On android,I am using JUnit to test the Amazon web server cognito which requires a context to access the shared preferences. I tried to mock the context, and to use android instrumentation tools but neither options worked. The context is being received, but I am unable to access shared preferences as I'm getting a null pointer.

Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to mock, you could try Mockito. You will need to find all that call that need to be mocked.

```
    final Context mockContext = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
    final SharedPreferences preferences = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences.class);
    Mockito.when(preferences.getString("<identitypool>.<key>", null)).thenReturn("someValue");
```